# Order Statistics Problem: Wackerly/Mendenhall/Scheaffer, 5th Ed., Problem 6.58

Tags: self-study, order-statistics

**Problem Statement:**

Suppose that the number of occurrences of a certain event in time
interval $(0,t)$ has a Poisson distribution. If we know that $n$ such events
have occurred in $(0,t),$ then the actual times, measured from $0,$ for the
occurrences of the event in question form an ordered set of random variables,
which we denote by $W_{(1)}\le W_{(2)}\le\cdots\le W_{(n)}.$ [$W_{(i)}$ actually
is the waiting time from $0$ until the occurrence of the $i$th event.] It can
be shown that the joint density function for $W_{(1)}, W_{(2)},\dots,W_{(n)}$
is given by
$$f(w_1, w_2,\dots,w_n)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{n!}{t^n},&w_1\le w_2\le\cdots\le w_n\\
0,&\text{elsewhere.}
\end{cases}
$$
[This is the density function for an ordered sample of size $n$ from a uniform
distribution on the interval $(0,t).$] Suppose that telephone calls coming
into a switchboard follow a Poisson distribution with a mean of ten calls per
minute. A slow period of $2$ minutes' duration had only four calls.

1. Find the probability that all four calls came in during the first
   minute; that is, find $P(W_{(4)}\le 1).$
2. Find the expected waiting time, from the start of the $2$-minute period,
   until the fourth call.

**My Work So Far:**

What's extremely confusing to me in this problem is how to interpret all the numbers I'm given. So I'm told the underlying Poisson distribution has $\lambda=10.$ Where does that figure into solving this problem, if at all? Then we're examining a slow period of $2$ minutes: where does that figure into solving this problem? Should $n=4$ in the joint density function above? Or should $n=10?$

I think if I could please have a nudge in the right direction for the first part, I imagine I could easily perform the integral to get the second.

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: You lost me at "I'm told ... $\lambda=10.$" Where was that stated in the problem? It might help to adapt your units of time measurement to the problem. A good unit would correspond to the full duration. Thus, for instance, (1) asks "conditional on assuming exactly four calls arrived during a given interval, find the probability that all four of those calls occurred in the first half of that interval." This appears to expose an ambiguity in the question: *how was the interval determined?* In many applications, it would be the time elapsed until the fourth call--but that's probably not intended.

Comment: BTW, the ambiguity can be resolved by ignoring most of the language in the problem and using only its assertion that you have "an ordered sample of size 4 from a uniform distribution on a given interval."  That permits a unique solution (which is simple to obtain).

Comment: Thanks, whuber. The $\lambda=10$ comes from this sentence: "Suppose that telephone calls coming into a switchboard follow a Poisson distribution with a mean of ten calls per minute." I was wondering whether I shouldn't do exactly what you mention, just blow past everything and use the joint distribution as-is with $n=4.$ Is that what you're recommending?

Comment: Thank you for your patience--although I reread the post several times, I must have been scanning for "10" rather than "ten."  And yes, I am recommending ignoring all the distractions that have been inserted in this question and using the "actionable" solid information it provides; namely, its explicit mathematical representation of the joint distribution of the event times (and their characterization in terms of a uniform sample).

Comment: Thanks again, whuber! You know, I get it that in the real world, you have to confront ambiguity all the time. In academia, it seems to me that students need to be exposed to that ambiguity *somewhat* so as to learn how to handle it. But this question was too much for me. Cheers.

Comment: Actually, I think the opposite may be the case. Textbook questions have the greatest possible need to be unambiguous.  It's ok to include distractors--passages that will cause a confused student to obtain the wrong answer--because those have pedagogic value.  But the question itself, to be at all useful and not frustrate the learner, must be absolutely clear.  Ambiguities in the real world are resolved by further inquiry--into what the problem really is, how to formulate it, what assumptions to make, and so on. Such inquiry is rarely possible with textbook problems.

Comment: True. Well, $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{4!}{t^4}\,dt$ doesn't converge, so that evidently is not what is intended. Maybe I do need to take the underlying Poisson distribution and calculate the joint distribution for the order statistics?

Comment: The integral isn't over $t,$ it's over the vectors $(w_1,\ldots, w_n)$ (for which $0\le w_1\le w_2\le \cdots \le w_n \le t$).  That's what the left hand side "$f(w_1,w_2,\ldots, w_n)$" is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] Only keeping this answer to make sense of the comments from whuber, which have the solution implicit in them.

Well, I've got an answer to Part 1, I hope:

We start with the underlying Poisson distribution:
$$p(y)=\frac{10^y\,e^{-10}}{y!},\; y=0, 1, 2,\dots$$
We will need the cumulative distribution function
$$F(y)
=P(Y\le y)
=\sum_{x=0}^y \frac{10^x\,e^{-10}}{x!}
=\frac{\Gamma(y+1, 10)}{\Gamma(y+1)}.$$
The function in the numerator is the upper incomplete gamma function.
This is a discrete distribution, so computing the order statistics is
completely different from continuous distributions. Following the [wikipedia
article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Dealing_with_discrete_variables), we define
\begin{align*}
p_1(y)&:=P(Y<y)
=F(y)-p(y)
=\frac{\Gamma(y+1, 10)}{\Gamma(y+1)}-\frac{10^y\,e^{-10}}{y!}
=\frac{\Gamma(y+1, 10)-10^y\,e^{-10}}{y!}\\
p_2(y)&:=P(Y=y)
=p(y)
=\frac{10^y\,e^{-10}}{y!}\\
p_3(y)&:=P(Y>y)
=1-F(y)
=1-\frac{\Gamma(y+1, 10)}{\Gamma(y+1)}.
\end{align*}
Now then, for the order statistics, we have that
$$P(W_{(k)}\le y)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{n}{j}(p_3(y))^j 
(p_1(y)+p_2(y))^{n-j}$$
in general, so that
\begin{align*}
P(W_{(4)}\le 1)
&=\sum_{j=0}^{10-4}\binom{10}{j}(p_3(1))^j (p_1(1)+p_2(1))^{10-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{6}\binom{10}{j}(p_3(1))^j (p_1(1)+p_2(1))^{10-j}.
\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{align*}
p_1(1)&=e^{-10}\\
p_2(1)&=10\,e^{-10}\\
p_3(1)&=1-11\,e^{-10}.
\end{align*}
Then we simplify
\begin{align*}
P(W_{(4)}\le 1)
&=\sum_{j=0}^{6}\binom{10}{j}\left(1-11\,e^{-10}\right)^j \left(11\,e^{-10}\right)^{10-j}\\
&\approx 1.30308\times 10^{-11}.
\end{align*}

[Correct Answer]

1. As whuber mentions in the comments, the probability of a call occurring in the first minute is $1/2$ with a uniform distribution. Hence the probability of all four calls occurring in the first minute is simply $1/16.$
2. We compute the expected value of $W_{(4)}.$ To do so, we need the density and distribution for the uniform distribution:
   \begin{align*}
   f(t)&=
   \begin{cases}
   \dfrac12, &t\in[0,2]\\
   0,&\text{elsewhere,}
   \end{cases}\\
   F(t)&=
   \begin{cases}
   0,&t<0\\
   \dfrac{t}{2},&t\in[0,2]\\
   1,&t>2.
   \end{cases}
   \end{align*}
   Then, according to the work done in Section 6.6 of the book, the density function for the maximum order statistic is given by
   \begin{align*}
   g_{(4)}(t)
   &=4\,[F(t)]^3 f(t)\\
   &=
   \begin{cases}
   4(t/2)^3(1/2),&t\in[0,2]\\
   0,&\text{elsewhere}
   \end{cases}\\
   &=
   \begin{cases}
   t^3/4,&t\in[0,2]\\
   0,&\text{elsewhere.}
   \end{cases}
   \end{align*}
   It follows that the expected value of $W_{(4)}$ is
   $$\int_0^2 \frac{t^4}{4}\,dt=\frac85.$$
   This makes sense: we would expect the value to be greater than the midpoint, but certainly not greater than $2.$

Comment: The value $1\times 10^{-11}$ is so obviously wrong, you should sit back and rethink your interpretation of the question.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered about that; but where are the errors? Is it the $n$ value?

Comment: Consider four independent uniform variables in an interval.  The chance that *any* value lies in the first half of the interval is (by definition of uniform!) exactly $1/2.$ Therefore the chance all four lie in the first half is $1/2^4 = 1/16.$  So, however you choose to perform the calculation, you should obtain $1/16$ as your answer!

Comment: @whuber Ok, that makes sense. How would I compute the expected waiting time in part 2?

Comment: The four events must be uniformly distributed within the first two minutes.

Comment: Is my (second) solution correct, as claimed?

Comment: You can check it with a quick simulation, such as this one in `R`: `mean(apply(matrix(runif(4e5, 0, 2), 4), 2, max))`.

Comment: Great, thanks! My answer certainly seems to be correct by that means.